# What is a correct way of using an implementation with an interface class in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I have a class `Child` and a class `Human` where `Human` has all the functions declared in `Child` as virtual functions. And a class `Child` inherits from `Human` class.

I want to use `Human` as a interface file to hide implementation in `Child`.

I didn't really set up a constructor, but I set up an `init()` function which initializes basic settings.

Now, what is a good way that I can use `Child` functions using `Human` interface file?

I tried

```
Human *John = new Child();
```

but I got the following errors.

```
main.cpp:7: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Child’
main.cpp:7: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘Human*’ in initialization
main.cpp:7: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘Child
```

I don't understand where `int*` came from either. None of my functions declared returns int*.

**edit**

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Human.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){

    Human *John = new Child();

    return 0;
}
```

**human.h**

```
#ifndef __HUMAN_h__
#define __HUMAN_h__


class Human
{
public:
    virtual void Init() = 0;
    virtual void Cleanup() = 0;
};


#endif
```

**Child.h**

```
#ifndef __CHILD_h__
#define __CHILD_h__

#include "Human.h"


class Child : public Human
{
public:
    void Init();
    void Cleanup();

};

#endif
```

**Child.cpp**

```
#include "Child.h"
void Child::Init()
{
}

void Child::Cleanup()
{
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CC = g++
INC = -I.
FLAGS = -W -Wall
LINKOPTS = -g

all: program

program: main.o Child.o
    $(CC) -Wall -o program main.o Child.o

main.o: main.cpp Human.h
    $(CC) -Wall -c main.cpp Human.h

Child.o: Child.cpp Child.h
    $(CC) -Wall -c Child.cpp Child.h

Child.h: Human.h

clean:
    rm -rf program
```

Comment: Please post more of your code. Also, just guessing since the code is not shown, but add a semicolon (`;`) to the end of your `Human` class definition ;)

Comment: Please provide a complete example, as described [here](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I edited and posted the codes above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to `#include "Child.h"` in your `cpp` file.  You can do this along with including `human.h` or you can not include `human.h` as that will be brought in automatically by the include within `child.h`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Child.h"
#include "Human.h"    // This is no longer necessary, as child.h includes it  
using namespace std;
int main(){
    Human *John = new Child();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re "This is no longer necessary, as child.h includes it" : I tend to be pedantic about that sort of thing. If my code uses constructs from Human.h, I will `#include "Human.h"` even if I know that Child.h necessarily must do that same #include.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the definition for the Child class in your main.cpp. Most probably you included Human.h:

```
#include "human.h"
```

instead of Child.h:

```
#include "child.h"
```

But that's a guess. What is certain is that the code that includes the definiton of the Child class is not available in the Main.cpp at the point where you have the error. This could be due to wrong or missing #include or missuse of the #ifdef precompiler directives. But to be able to better help you we need more of the code like the declaration of "Child.h" and "Human.h" and the full code of the "Main.cpp".

For the interface part. To have a truly clean interface you should not implement any function in it. That's the best practice in using interfaces. In C++ you can implement some of the functions but that would not be an interface (aka as pure virtual or abstract class) but a virtual class (which still can't be instatiated but are not that abstract so that they can be considered interfaces)

Comment: You posted the code just when I was still writing my answer :)

Comment: It's a good limitation to have just one answer selected. I don't mind someone else getting their answer approved as long as the problem is solved :) but thanks for your comment ;)